# JavaScript: user closes banner and doesn't show banner next 30 days

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript script that may hide banners for a specific time after the user interact with them and close them with the X button.

**Banner 01** may hide for 1 day (24 hours) when the user closes this banner.

**Banner 02** may hide for 30 days when the user closes this banner.

Now my code doesn't work as I want and the user can't even close one of these banners.

When I use part of Javascript which is designed for Banner 01 and test it Banner 01 works fine show after the user closes this banner after 24 hours will show again.

I need this exact functionality for Banner 02 but not for 24 hours but for 30 days. These two banners may work together on one site.

Is there any solution to how I can use these two banners with functionality for each of them which I mentioned above?

```js
// Banner 01
const header = document.getElementById('mainheader')
const bannercloser = document.getElementById('bannercloser')
const banner = document.getElementById('mainbanner')

function getCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function checkCookie() {
  if (getCookie('banner')) {
    banner.classList.add('disabled');
    header.classList.add('disabled');
  } else {
    banner.classList.remove('disabled');
    header.classList.remove('disabled');
  }
}
checkCookie()

bannercloser.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    banner.classList.remove('disabled');
    header.classList.remove('disabled');
  }, 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "; expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = "banner=1" + expires + "; path=/";
  banner.classList.add('disabled');
  header.classList.add('disabled');
})

//Banner 02
const cookiesCloser = document.getElementById('cookiesCloser')
const cookiesBanner = document.getElementById('cookiesBanner')

function getCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function checkCookie() {
  if (getCookie('banner')) {
    cookiesBanner.classList.add('disabled');
  } else {
    cookiesBanner.classList.remove('disabled');
  }
}
checkCookie()

cookiesCloser.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    cookiesBanner.classList.remove('disabled');
  }, 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "; expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = "banner=1" + expires + "; path=/";
  cookiesBanner.classList.add('disabled');
})
```

```css
#cookiesBanner {
  background: pink;
}

.announcement-banner {
  background: orange;
}

#cookiesBanner.disabled {
  display: none;
}

.announcement-banner.disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbanner" class="announcement-banner">
  <div class="container-banner">
    <strong>Banner 01</strong>
    <button id="bannercloser">X</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="cookiesBanner">
  <p>Banner 02</p>
  <button id="cookiesCloser">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to have duplicate functions in your script. That will cause only the latter function to be valid. Is that intentional?

Comment: No, I need to have functional both of them as I mentioned above. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Hi, it would probably be useful if you use your browser devtools to find errors and also run your code through the W3C Validator - it will point out your duplicate functions (as mentioned by @EmmielZuurbier) - you have some non-legal JavaScript so things won't work. You may also like to read up about what a function is/does.

Answer (score 2):

Both your banners have similar behavior. The only difference between them is some sort of configuration (name of cookie, expiration date, etc.). These configurations can be passed as *data-attributes* on the HTML elements. For example:

```html
<div class="banner" data-name="cookie-banner" data-expire="30">
  ...
</div>
```

In your JavaScript file you could try to find every element on your page that should have *banner-like* behavior and loop over them. Then for each banner read out the configuration set by the attributes and listen for click events.

Instead of determining wether the banner should be hidden, try to determine if the banner should be *shown*. This way the banner is always hidden, unless there is no cookie.

This method is also very extendable. Adding another banner element with its own name and expire date will only require you to add another banner element into the HTML.

The example below won't run in the stack-snippet because of security reasons regarding cookies, but you should try this on your local environment and see it run.

```js
function getCookie(name) {
  const nameEQ = name + "=";
  const ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function setCookie(name, expire) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (expire * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  document.cookie = `${name}=1; expires=${d.toGMTString()}; path=/`;
}

// Gets an array of banner elements.
const banners = document.querySelectorAll('.banner');

// Loop over each banner.
banners.forEach(banner => {
  // Read the name and expire values from the data attributes.
  const { name, expire } = banner.dataset;
  
  // The attributes contain strings as values.
  // But we require a number to do the date calculation later on.
  // So the string must be converted to a number.
  const daysToExpire = Number(expire);
  
  // If the cookie is not there, then show the element.
  if (!getCookie(name)) {
    banner.classList.add('visible');
  }

  // Listen for the click on each banner.
  // The event object will give you information on what element has been clicked.
  // This way you can detect if the button inside the banner has been clicked.
  // Set the cookie the button has been clicked and remove the banner from the DOM.
  banner.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.closest('.banner-close')) {
      setCookie(name, daysToExpire);
      banner.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.banner {
  display: none;
}

.banner.visible {
  display: block;
}

#cookies-banner {
  background: pink;
}

#announcement-banner {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="announcement-banner" class="banner" data-name="announcement-cookie" data-expire="1">
  <div class="container-banner">
    <strong>Banner 01</strong>
    <button class="banner-close">X</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cookies-banner" class="banner" data-name="cookies-cookie" data-expire="30">
  <p>Banner 02</p>
  <button class="banner-close">X</button>
</div>
```